# Scroll up a div when showing which is initially on hide in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery.

I want to show a div based on its id, and while showing it I need to scroll up.

The div is initially hidden.

I tried running the following code but it is not scrolling up, it is showing at the bottom of the page and I need to scroll down to view the div.

### html

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#registerDiv" id="register">Redeem</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<section id="registerDiv" ng-controller="registerCtrl">
<!-- section will show when link is clicked -->
</section>
```

### js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#registerDiv").hide();
    $("#register").click(function(){
        $("#registerDiv").show("slow"); //need to slideUp here
    });
});
```

Can somebody please help me fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really confused, what you mean by `slideUp`?!

Comment: i mean scroll up the particular section while showinf

Comment: registerDiv whick is initiallly on hide. when i click that redeem button i am showing registerDiv , here i need to scroll up

Comment: if you know exactly what you want/need, then please point to it, _a picture is worth a thousand words_ https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>You just need to use `.slideToggle()`.</del>

Update: you need to display `#registerDiv` before you get `.show().offset().top`
then hide and `slideDown()` after scrolling.

See example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#registerDiv").hide();
  $("#register").click(function() {
    var dt = $("#registerDiv").show().offset().top
    $("#registerDiv").hide();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: dt
      },
      'slow', function() {
        $("#registerDiv").slideDown();
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="page-scroll" href="#registerDiv" id="register">Redeem</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<p>some conetent before</p>
<p>some conetent before</p>
<p>some conetent before</p>
<p>some conetent before</p>
<p>some conetent before</p>

<section id="registerDiv" ng-controller="registerCtrl">
  something to show this section when clicked
</section>

<p>some conetent after</p>
<p>some conetent after</p>
<p>some conetent after</p>
<p>some conetent after</p>
<p>some conetent after</p>
<p>some conetent after</p>
<p>some conetent after</p>
<p>some conetent after</p>
```

Comment: thanks for reply . but i need some thing like this [click here](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/) . assume that the button is clicked i am showing some section that needs to scroll up. i used that just for reference i want this functionality using jquery

Comment: $("#registerDiv").hide(); before you animate is not necessary

Comment: How? in this line `$("#registerDiv").show().offset().top` this will show the div So you need to back to be hidden.

Comment: no no i dont need to hidden after show().offset().top

Comment: @SukumarDhoni So why you you hide that before click event in your code ?

Comment: the div needs to hide before i click , when clicked it has to show and scroll up and no need i hide my div before click fun not after. is that clear

Comment: I think .slideDown() needs this div to be hidden before you call.

Answer (score 0):

Gave you Rough Idea.Now upto you how you use your logical skills.Happy coding :)

```
<ul>
    <li >
       <button id="register" style="margin-top: 50%;">Redeem</button>
    </li>
 </ul> 

<section id="registerDiv" ng-controller="registerCtrl" style="display:none">
I am on the top
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#register").click(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0,0);

        $('#registerDiv').animate({
        'marginTop' : "-50%" //moves top
        });

        $('#registerDiv').show();

    });
});
</script>
```